# looks like the mark ' : ' in MATLAB and 'numpy.arange' in Python work differently

Tags: matlab, python-3.x

I just found that ':' in MATLAB and 'numpy.arange' in Python print different result.

In MATLAB:

```
K>> TEMP = 1:125*(1-0.66):100000;

K>> fprintf('%.15f, %.15f, %.15f, %.15f, %.15f\n', TEMP(1), TEMP(2), TEMP(3), TEMP(4), TEMP(5))
1.000000000000000, 43.499999999999993, 85.999999999999986, 128.499999999999970, 170.999999999999970

K>> fprintf('%.15f', TEMP(1544))
65578.500000000000000
```

I'm using these values as indices of some array, after rounding up.
I expected TEMP(4) is '128.499999999999979', but '128.499999999999970' is printed.
TEMP(4) is not a problem, because both of Python and MATLAB are printing '128' after rounding.
But, values after TEMP(1544) could be a problem.
In MATLAB 's TEMP(1544) : 65578.500000000000000
In Python 's TEMP[1543] : 65578.499999999989199

After rounding these,
'65579' in MATLAB
'65578' in Python

So, I refer wrong index of an array..

Same testing in python, result is as bellow.

in Python:

```
>>> r = Decimal(125 * (1-0.66)).quantize(Decimal('0.000000000000001'), roun
ding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
>>> r
Decimal('42.499999999999993')
>>> TEMP = np.arange(Decimal(1), Decimal(100000), r, dtype=np.dtype(Decimal))
>>> print("%.15f, %.15f, %.15f, %.15f, %.15f" % (TEMP[0], TEMP[1], TEMP[2],
 TEMP[3], TEMP[4]))
1.000000000000000, 43.499999999999993, 85.999999999999986, 128.499999999999972, 170.999999999999972
>>> print("%.15f" % TEMP[1543])
65578.499999999989199
```

As you see, in Python, the result including 15th digit is printed.

How can I get same result with MATLAB in Python?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems more related to roundup error of floating point numbers, and not to the `:` operator. Why do you expect the results to be the same? These are probably slightly different algorithms, so no reason to expect exactly the same result

Comment: When I use these values as indices of some array, it could be a problem. I just updated content.

Comment: @Hong You can not use those values as indices to an array, they are floats. You need integers

Comment: Looks like a problem with the value types, not the function itself. Try increasing the tolerance, and check the results. I'd go with 10-4 or 10-3
you could also try to round first to 0.1 and then do the final round, which should give you the same indices in both cases.
@Ander: yes but if you round 0.5 up, it is a problem ;)

Comment: @Y.S Then OP just needs a different way of obtaining the index. If the returned index needs a precision of 10 decimals, either it does not matter (for the overall algorithm) which one its using or hes going to have big numerical problems elsewhere also. You can not rely on accuracy after 6 or 7 decimals in a computer, that is Numerical computing 101.

Comment: @AnderBiguri
Hence reducing the tolerance to e-04 or e-03.

Comment: What version and architecture (32bit or 64bit) of MATLAB are you using?  I can't reproduce your MATLAB results.  I tried this on three different versions of MATLAB, R2017a (latest), R2011b 64bit, and R2011b 32bit and all give essentially the same results as Python.  The only way I can reproduce your results is manually changing `TEMP` to a `single`.

Comment: You appear to be using `Decimal` in python. In my understanding, it doesn't follow the normal floating point rules. What happens when you don't use it?

Comment: @horchler: I tried that when testing Hong's code, it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @Y.S Thanks for your comment, even if I could get same result after modifying you mentioned(reducing tolerance), unfortunately I have to convert MATLAB codes to python as it is, without any modifying.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Thanks for comment, I'm using MATLAB 8.3.0.532 (R2014a) - 64bits. And I get this result using double type array.

Comment: @horchler Thanks for comment. I tried it again without using Decimal, the result is same as using Decimal..

Comment: @hung: What operating system?  I can't reproduce this on windows 7 64bit with R2014a.  Is there any way you can test another MATLAB version?

Comment: @TheBlackCat Oh, I'm sorry, I think I took some mistakes. I tested with 1:125*(1-0.66):100000, not 1:125*(1-0.66):1000000.. You can check the result after modify '1000000' to '100000'. I'll edit the content. I'm so sorry to have confused you.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I think this problem is solved. I just noticed that MATLAB's ':' and numpy arange() are using different logic. Please refer below page. http://web.archive.org/web/20120213165003/http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4FLI96/index.html